# How to Paginate a type as you search with Ajax in a Django app

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, pagination

I'm implementing a type as you search with ajax in a Django app with pagination. I want results to refresh as the user types their search term in the database instead of a form with a submit button. I'm using Django's inbuilt pagination to paginate the data and display it in the template.

Right now:

- HTTP GET parameters are handled in Django views and make our view capture the user’s query.
- The Django view handle Ajax requests and respond to them properly with a JSON response containing the new (template) results.
- JavaScript and jQuery send an Ajax request to our view once the user starts typing in the HTML search box.
- This request will include the term so the server can return relevant results.
- Once our view returns the JSON response, our JS code will use it to change the information presented to the user without a page-refresh.

Problem:

At the moment, When I receive my searched results and go to the second page, I receive results unrelated to the search query which I believe is lost.
E.g search 'John', I have a list of objects(artists name) with 'John' as its name. When I press the next page because there are many pages of John, I lose this 'John' query and it shows me the second page of all my artists list disregarding my search parameter john.

Is there a way to paginate my results without it reloading (dynamically loading) and losing my URL query 'John' when I change pages?

(js.html file has the link to the artist.js file and hosting via CDN for jquery)

views.py

'''

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import JsonResponse

def artist_list(request):
    url_parameter = request.GET.get('q')

    if url_parameter:
        artists = Pagination(request, Artist.objects.filter(name__icontains=url_parameter)
    else:
        artists = Pagination(request, Artist.objects.all()

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string(
        template_name='artist_replaceable_content.html', context={'artists': artists}
    )
        
        data_dict = {'html_from_view': html}
        return JsonResponse(data=data_dict, safe=False)

    return render(request, 'artist.html', context={'artists': artists})
```

'''

artist.html

'''

```
   {% load static %}
   {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
   {% block content %}
   {% include "css.html" %}
    <div class="container-fluid bg-soft">
     <main class="content">                                               
      <h2 class="h4">Artist_List</h2>                         
       <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><span class="fas fa-search" id="search-icon"></span></span>
        </div>                         
           <input class="form-control" id="searchInput" name='Search' placeholder="Search" type="text" aria-label="user search">
        </div>                        
      <div class="border bg-white" id="replaceable-content">
       {% include 'artist_replaceable_content.html' %}

    </div>
    </main>
  </div>
  {% include "js.html" %}
  {% endblock %}
```

'''

artist_replaceable_content.html

'''

```
{% load static %}

{% if artists %}
    {% for artist in artists %}
       <div class="card hover-state">
       <h3 class="h5">{{ artists.title }}</h3>
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      <span class="font-weight-normal text-gray">No artists found!</span>
{% endif %}
         <div class="card-footer">
         <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
         <ul class="pagination">
         {% if artists.has_other_pages %}
             {% if artists.has_previous %}
               <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="page=1">First</a></li>
               <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ artists.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
             {% endif %}                                 
             {% for i in artists.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if artists.number == i %}
                   <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                {% elif i > artists.number|add:'-5' and i < artists.number|add:'5' %}
                   <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }} </a></li>
                {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
             {% if artists.has_next %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ artists.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
             {% endif %}
         {% endif %}
      </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="font-weight-bold small">Showing<b>{{ artists.start_index {{artists.end_index }}</b> out of <b>{{ artists.paginator.count }}</b> entries</div>
      </div>
```

'''

artist.js:

'''

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 const search_Input = $("#searchInput")
 const artists_content = $('#replaceable-content')
 const search_icon = $('#search-icon')

 const endpoint = '/artists/'
 const delay_by_in_ms = 700
 let scheduled_function = false

 // getJSON() method to send an Ajax request to the endpoint alongside the parameters.
 let ajax_call = function (endpoint, request_parameters) {
   $.getJSON(endpoint, request_parameters)
      .done(response => {
          // fade out artists_content, replace and fade in artists_content
          artists_content.fadeTo('fast', 0).promise().then(() => {
          artists_content.html(response['html_from_view'])
          artists_content.fadeTo('fast', 1)     
          })
      })
 }
 // start
 search_Input.on('keyup', function () {
         event.preventDefault();

     const request_parameters = {
         q: $(this).val() // value of user_input: the HTML element with ID user-input
     }

     // if scheduled_function is NOT false, cancel the execution of the function
     if (scheduled_function) {
         clearTimeout(scheduled_function)
     }
     // setTimeout returns the ID of the function to be executed
     scheduled_function = setTimeout(ajax_call, delay_by_in_ms, endpoint, request_parameters)
     })
});
```

'''
urls.py

'''

```
 from django.urls import path
 from core import views as core_views

 urlpatterns = [

     path("artists/", core_views.artists_view, name="artists"),
 ]
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of custom template tags for this task, these are simple functions that will accept or not parameters and result return a result, you'll be able to load them in your template and use them as any other built-in Django template, you can create a template tag which can construct a url automatically by passing the necessary arguments for your request.

You can read more of them in the following link: [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/)

For this task, you'll need three things:

1. The query itself that you are requesting
2. The path to where you are requesting this information
3. The page number you are requesting

To keep this example simple, every time we request a query through AJAX, the server will return that same query back to the front-end as follows:

#### views.py file

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import JsonResponse

def artist_list(request):
    url_parameter = request.GET.get('q')

    if url_parameter:
        artists = Pagination(request, Artist.objects.filter(name__icontains=url_parameter)
    else:
        artists = Pagination(request, Artist.objects.all()

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string(
        template_name='artist_replaceable_content.html', context={'artists': artists, 'url_parameter': url_parameter}
    )
        
        data_dict = {'html_from_view': html}
        return JsonResponse(data=data_dict, safe=False)

    return render(request, 'artist.html', context={'artists': artists})
```

**Please check out the context we are returning with every AJAX request response (Context)**

Now it's time to build-up our custom template tag:

To create our custom template tags, we will need to create a templatetags folder inside our app folder, within this templatetags folder we add the respective **init**.py file to allow Python treat this folder as a package, and a .py file with any name you desire, for example: **custom_tags.py**

#### Inside out custom_tags.py file

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_query(url, query, page):
    """
        DOCSTRING: The get_query custom template tag will construct a URL for further use in pagination based
                    on the parameters received.
    """
    return url + '?query=' + query + '&page=' + page
```

**Note that you will need to restart your servers in order for your template tags to be registered.**

#### Next step is loading them in your template as follows:

```
{% load static %}

<!-- Loading Custom Tags -->
{% load custom_tags %}

{% if artists %}
    {% for artist in artists %}
       <div class="card hover-state">
       <h3 class="h5">{{ artists.title }}</h3>
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      <span class="font-weight-normal text-gray">No artists found!</span>
{% endif %}
         <div class="card-footer">
         <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
         <ul class="pagination">
         {% if artists.has_other_pages %}
             {% if artists.has_previous %}
               <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="page=1">First</a></li>
               <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ artists.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
             {% endif %}                                 
             {% for i in artists.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if artists.number == i %}
                   <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                {% elif i > artists.number|add:'-5' and i < artists.number|add:'5' %}
                   <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }} </a></li>
                {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
             {% if artists.has_next %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ artists.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
             {% endif %}
         {% endif %}
      </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="font-weight-bold small">Showing<b>{{ artists.start_index {{artists.end_index }}</b> out of <b>{{ artists.paginator.count }}</b> entries</div>
      </div>
```

#### Making use of the template tag

```
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{% get_query url url_parameter artists.next_page_number %}"
```

#### Suggestions

1. I would recommend using partial templates for this task, this way you will not need to deal with removing and adding the templates again with the updated data as the page number.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I have tried this solution and it works partially. The only downside is it keeps the query for the first link clicked: e.g keeps query value for page 1 to page 2. but from page 2 to 3, the query is lost.